# What does "for x, u in enumerate(...)" mean?

Tags: python

I adapted a function to solve a problem in my project but I don't really get how it works.
Btw a user list is stored in self.__users, it is read from users.txt.

```
def delete(self, nick):
    for x, u in enumerate(self.__users):    # <----- Just this line
        if u._nickname == nick:
            del self.__users[x]
            return
```

Does this mean it will separate each user and give them a number? I don't understand that line.

Comment: I think this might help https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/enumerate-in-python/

Comment: And if you can run the code, just add a line `print( x, u )` indented below the for line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep... the `enumerate` built-in function will create a list something like:

```
[(0, user1),
 (1, user2),
 (2, user3)]
```

Note that I don't know any info about your `self.__users` that's why I putting that way....
So this line `for x, u in enumerate(self.__users):` will return for `x` the index and for the `u` your user.

Hope that helped

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section *Answer Well-Asked Questions*, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks... I'll read that and try to make better next time

Answer (score 0):

Enumerate generates two variables from an array,
The first one is an array element's index, the second one is its element itself.
So for array ['x', 'y', 'z' ], the initial values for these variables will be 0 and  'x' respectively.

Comment: `enumerate` returns a tuple where the first element is the index and the second element the current value from the iterable. So switching the usage of `x` and `u` as you suggested is false.